# Running cucumber-Java configuration in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, cucumber-java

I am new to cucumber and Jenkins. Currently we have our BDD tests implemented and running fine locally. I want to trigger the execution using Jenkins job and need help on it. 
We have gradle as our build tool. Below is our gradle file -

```
task cucumberByFeatures() {
    dependsOn assemble, compileTestJava
    doLast {
        javaexec {
            main = "cucumber.api.cli.Main"
            classpath = configurations.cucumberRuntime
            args = ['--plugin', 'pretty',
                    '--plugin', 'json:build/reports/cucumber-report.json',
                    '--glue', 'src/main/java/com/medtronic/neuro/functionaltest/Steps',
                    'src/cucumber/features',
            ]
        }
    }
```

Locally we can run the tests by going to intended feature file or folder and select Run option on right click.

Comment: can anybody help me in this? surprisingly no one replied to the post even after a week

Answer (score 1):

You can run your tests as Integration test on Jenkins.

All you need to do is to create a profile which brings up your application on a server like cargo or spring boot.

Than you need to make your cucumber test executed from that profile.

I have a reference from maven to achieve it:
http://www.weblogism.com/item/334/integration-tests-with-cucumber-selenium-and-maven

You need to convert the maven instructions to gradle accordingly.